# How to call user function in Mozilla Addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Can some one tell me what is wrong with code. Here i want to send POst request to webpage when clicked on Context menu. Post data would be url that is clicked.

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var cm = require("sdk/context-menu");
var Request = require('sdk/request').Request;
var self = require("sdk/self");


function sendRequest(turl) {
    Request({url: 'myurl.com',content: {data: turl},onComplete: function (response) {console.log(response.text);}}).post();
};

var script = "self.on('click', function (node, data) {" +
             "sendRequest(node);" +
             "});";

cm.Item({
  label: "Save To nbojanapu",
context: cm.SelectorContext("a"),
contentScript: script

});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The error i get is 
System JS : ERROR javascript:self.on('click', function (node, data) {sendRequest(node);});:1 - ReferenceError: sendRequest is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, that sendRequest is not defined for the contentScript in the context menu. You would have to use the messaging function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu#message)

```
var script = "self.on('click', function(node, data) {" +
             "  self.postMessage(node.href);" +
             "});";

cm.Item({
  label: "Save to nbojanapu",
  context: cm.SelectorContext("a"),
  contentScript: script,
  onMessage: sendRequest
});
```

So instead of calling sendRequest directly in the contentScript, it's called in the message event handler (which I attached directly in the constructor of the item). The message is sent from the contentScript using the self.postMessage method, which, by the way, doesn't support making structured clones of an Object, or in other words, if you'd send the whole node with a message it would be broken on the receiving end (see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_postMessage). Since you seem to just want the href attribute, I just send that directly.